# Using csc.exe to recursively find .cs files doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, zsh, oh-my-zsh, csc

I have the following CSC command:

`$` `csc -out:dist/program.exe src/program/*.cs -recurse:*.cs`

This gives me the following error: `no matches found: -recurse:*.cs`

Does anyone have any idea why the `-recurse` option is not recognised/working properly in this case?

Comment: Zsh probably handles the wildcards instead of giving it to `csc`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/335210/apt-get-wildcard-with-zsh

Comment: @Caramiriel Thanks, that was the problem indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728007/using-csc-exe-to-recursively-find-cs-files-doesnt-seem-to-work#comment98135018_55728007) by [Caramiriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1688785/caramiriel) using ZSH handles the wildcards instead of giving them to `csc.exe` and because it doesn't find any files that match it the error `no matches found: <pattern>` is thrown.

More information in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/335210).

Answered to make it more useful for others rather than leave it as a comment only as discussed in meta posts ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268), [3](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294792)).